# how to unit test netty handler that inclued i/o file in it?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq, netty

in channelRead of the channelhandleradapter i am writing to a file ,
i know how to use embeddedchannel to unit test netty handlers , 
but how to unit test this handler when we are doing file I/O inside it(ChannelRead) ? something like mock with no i/O file dependency .

```
public class LogHandler : ChannelHandlerAdapter
   {

       const string Path = @"L:\Log.txt";
        public override void ChannelActive(IChannelHandlerContext context)
        {
            base.ChannelActive(context);
        }

        public override Task WriteAsync(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
        {
            Logger.SentLog(message as IByteBuffer);
            return context.WriteAsync(message as IByteBuffer);
        }

        public override void ChannelRead(IChannelHandlerContext context, object message)
        {

            string msg = Convertor.ByteBufferToString(message as IByteBuffer);
            IByteBuffer initialMessage = Unpooled.Buffer(1024);
            byte[] messageBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(msg);
            initialMessage.WriteBytes(messageBytes);


            using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(Path, true))
            {
                writer.WriteLine($"(Read){System.DateTime.Now} -> {BitConverter.ToString(messageBytes).Replace("-"," ")}");
            }

            if (msg != "Timeout")
            {
                base.ChannelRead(context, message);
            }

        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You class depends on the `StreamWriter` class. You need to change your class in such way that you provide these dependency from the caller and that you can mock it in your unit tests. Therefore, you could create a simple wrapper class for the `StreamWriter` instantiation, use this wrapper class in your class and inject it in the constructor/ per setter. And in your unit test setup up the mock to return a local `StreamWriter` that you can use to verify the content written.

Answer (score 0):

You can still use `EmbeddedChannel`. Just use `writeInbound(...)` and verify it returns `false`. Then once you called `channel.finish()` verify what was written in the file.